# MongoDB seeding and replication

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reverse-proxy, replicaset

I have this small project i am working on it but i got stuck with mongodb replicaset and reverse proxy. I explain myself better.

I have a Web application running one instance(just a simple web page). And this application by default connects to port 3000. I used nginx reverse proxy to use port 80 instead of 3000 (and this works)

This application is a nodejs app, and in its configuration files, it should connect to mongodb on port on

```
mongodb://10.0.1.100:27017/posts (value exported by code into my instance)
```

to display some random posts.

On my mongod.conf I bind my IP to 0.0.0.0 and set port to 27017

but when i log on my app instance and seed my mongoDB (it get seeded succesfully) but when i run

```
npm start
```

I got an error that the port 3000 is already used by another service.

So, my point is, i want to connect to my /posts from my web page, without having to type  :/posts

this is my mongod.conf:

```
# mongod.conf



# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/



# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:



# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log



# network interfaces
net:
  port: <%= @port %>
  bindIp: <%= @bind_ip %>




#processManagement:



#security:



#operationProfiling:



#replication:



#sharding:



## Enterprise-Only Options:



#auditLog:



#snmp:
```

and in the attribute i set:

```
default['mongodb']['port'] = 27017
default['mongodb']['bind_ip'] = '0.0.0.0'
```

Question Bonus:

```
mongodb://10.0.1.100:27017/posts
```

This value has been exported in the envroment variables, but as i need to set a replication over 2 more mongodb, i tried to insert in line separated but commas, but i get an error. is there a way how to export multiple env value under one variable name?

I hope i explained myself clearly and thank you in advance guys.

Comment: Should `npm start` be starting the mongod service?

Comment: I have a script which does that. And the service is up and running